# Converting String Array into hexadecimal array

Tags: .net, arrays

I have a string array

```
Receivedbyte[0]=5A
Receivedbyte[1]=3A
Receivedbyte[2]=7A
Receivedbyte[3]=60
```

I want to treat them as hex numbers and xor each of the value by 0x20.
so I want my data to be 
0x5A ^0x20 in the 0th location. and so on.

I Tried the following , but an error comes which says, input string is not in correct format.

```
static public string[] escapeFix(string[] Receivedbyte)
{         
    uint temp = Convert.ToUInt32(Receivedbyte[1]);

    temp = temp ^ 0x20;
    Receivedbyte[0] = Convert.ToString(temp);
    Receivedbyte[1] = Receivedbyte[2];
    Receivedbyte[2] = Receivedbyte[3];
    return Receivedbyte;
}
```

Comment: Which language are you targeting? C#?

Comment: I am very confused about why your code seemingly discards `Receivedbyte[0]` and shuffles all of the rest one place down...

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToUInt32` tries to parse decimal string, but your input is hex, hence the error. Try `byte.Parse(ReceivedBytes[1], NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)`.

Also does `uint.ToString()` convert to a decimal representation. Do you mean to convert to a hex? Then you should `.ToString("X")`.

What you code does once the parsing is ok, is in complete contradiction to what you describe it's supposed to.
You'll end up with [ "26", "7A", "60", "60" ], where "26" is the (decimal) representation of 0x3A ^ 0x20, twenty-six.

Why are you messing with strings in the first place? Can't you just use a `byte[]`? Like:

```
public static byte[] EscapeFix(byte[] receivedBytes)
{
    return receivedBytes.Select(b => (byte)(b ^ 0x20)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse the string as hexadecimal values first, then XOR before converting back to strings.

```
void Main()
{
    var receivedBytes = new string[] { "5A", "3A", "7A", "60" };

    escapeFix(receivedBytes);
}

public static string[] escapeFix(string[] bytes)
{
    return bytes
        .Select(b => Convert.ToByte(b, 16) ^ 0x20)
        .Select(b => b.ToString("X"))
        .ToArray();
}
```